# Value of time of the beginning of today

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the number of times a user has logged in since the beginning of each day.

```
SELECT user_id 
    FROM users 
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, user_login, NOW()) < 12 
        AND user_id = 1
```

This sql checks the difference between the login and the current time which is wrong.
What should go instead of NOW() to indicate midnight+1min of that day and check the logins throughout that day?

Comment: what is your table schema?

Comment: user_id | user_login. that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your code, the question is rather about mySQL and not PHP. Use

`CURDATE()`

instead of NOW() since TIMESTAMPDIFF will use this as 'Current Day, 00:00:00'

To get the end of the current day use

`CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

so your where-clause should be

`WHERE user_login BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

provided you have the user_login field in the DATE format, otherwise you would have to cast that accordingly.

Comment: I tried putting CURDATE() like you said instead of NOW() but my sql is wrong so I can you help me rewrite it? I need to check if the user logged in for the first time or not. If it is i want to return the count 1

Comment: Ok, so you want to know if the user already logged in that specific day? So that would be `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE user_login BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND user_id=1`

Comment: Being picky, `BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` includes tomorrow 0:00 as well. But that's easy to fix by replacing `a BETWEEN b AND c` with `a>=b AND a<c`. Nice answer anyway.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario That's true, but given the fact that a query made tomorrow 0:00 would yield a different CURDATE(), in gadgetster's scenario this does not really matter. But to be minded especially in scenarios where CURDATE() is replaced by any other time.

Comment: That's right. We shouldn't have future dates in this particular scenario... in theory :)